# javascript | não está definindo função "tabela"

Tags: javascript

**Este é o meu código, projeto casa de câmbio**

```
function criarMoeda (Nome, sigla, valor) {
    return {Nome, sigla, valor};
 } 

 let moedas = {
     usd: criarMoeda('Dólar','USD', 5.56810),
     eur: criarMoeda('Euro','EUR', 6.63457),
     gbp: criarMoeda('Libra','GBP', 7.64738),
     jpy: criarMoeda('Iene', 'JPY', 0.05093),
     ars: criarMoeda('Peso', 'ARS', 0.06033)
 };
   
 let casa = {
     taxa: 0.10
 }

casa.proporCompra = function (moeda, quantidade) {
    let valorAjustado = moeda.valor * (1 + this.taxa);
    return valorAjustado * quantidade;
}
casa.proporVenda = function (moeda, quantidade) {
    let valorAjustado = moeda.valor * (1 - this.taxa);
    return valorAjustado * quantidade;
}

casa.proporTroca = function (moeda1, qtd1, moeda2, qtd2) {
    let valorCompra = this.proporCompra (moeda1 , qtd1);
    let valorVenda = this.proporvenda (moeda2,qtd2);

    return valorVenda - valorCompra;
}

casa.criarTabela = function(moedas) {
    let tabela = [];

    for (let moeda in moedas) {
        tabela.push({
            "Moeda": moedas[moeda].nome + ' (' + moedas[moeda]. sigla + ')',
        "Valor de venda": this.proporVenda (moedas[moeda], 1),
        "Valor de compra": this.proporCompra (moedas[moeda], 1)
        });       
    }

    return tabela;
}
```

Ao digitar a função "tabela" retorna assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tabela is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Answer (score 3):

O problema é o escopo da variável.
Você está criando ela com `let` dentro da função, sendo assim, ela existe somente no dentro da função.
Você deveria atingir o retorno da função a essa variável:

```js
casa.criarTabela = function(moedas) { 
 tabela = [];

 for (let moeda in moedas) {
    tabela.push({
        "Moeda": moedas[moeda].nome + ' (' + moedas[moeda]. sigla + ')',
    "Valor de venda": this.proporVenda (moedas[moeda], 1),
    "Valor de compra": this.proporCompra (moedas[moeda], 1)
    });       
 }

 return tabela;

}

let tabela = casa.criarTabela(moedas);
```

Comment: voce poderia mostrar como ficaria no código por favor?

Comment: Bata adicionar essa chamada logo abaixo da definição da função.

Comment: valeuuuu irmão, agora deu certo! muito obrigado

Comment: Que bom. Nesse caso marque essa resposta como aceita por favor.